# How does an oscillating charged particle create a light wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

I read that if a charged particle undergoes shm, it will produce Lightwave,  so I checked if the equations worked out,  and this is what I got
[image]

That doesn't look like a sine wave.... 
And if it isn't a sine wave, then it can't be light,  which means that an oscillating charged particle doesn't produce light, which isn't the case, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For sufficient large distance the wave solution is dominant in front of the rest of the solution that only encodes the details of the source. You may try to do a dipole expanssion and see what terms survives in the limit of large distance times a surface term $4\pi r^2$

Comment: try to see this: http://www.physicspages.com/2015/01/18/electric-dipole-time-varying-potentials-lorentz-gauge-condition/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electric field is a vector. Find the magnitude of the component of the vector parallel to the charged particle's motion. For large $x$, this should approximate a sine or cosine function. To an observer at point $P$, the oscillating field will look like there is a transverse wave passing by in addition to the largely static field pointing directly away from the particle.